# Google OAuth2 spring boot JSON API login

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2, google-signin

I'm developing a backend in spring boot for mobile app with google sign in. I have found several samples of google sign in, but none of them demonstrate behaviour of what I need.
I need simple security using OAuth2 tokens with Google as a provider.
I need the following flow:
Mobile App sign in -> obtain google token in app -> send token to backend -> receive secured data

I did some research on that topic, but none of my attempts seem to work.
Can anybody show me some working example of how does this work?

I assume, that app will use Google token just for the login and then use tokens from my backend - Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just view googles' signIn functionality as a way the user can provide you an email address about which you can be sure it is properly authenticated.. 
Just send the mail address from the frontend to your backend (with a normal jquery.post for example) and associate your own information in your database with that mail address.

To ensure that the user not just manipulated your javascript and sent a not verified email address to your backend that is not his own verify the auth token. there are libaries to do so as described here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have successfully authenticated with google, now I'm facing another problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332539/multiple-client-ids-spring-security-config). Would you please take a look on it?