# Multiple client ids spring security config

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, google-signin, google-oauth

I have successfully implemented Google Sign-In on iOS with following application.yml:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
      prefer-token-info: true
    client:
      client-id: xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
      access-token-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo
      client-authentication-scheme: form
      scope: email,profile
```

Now I need to add configuration for Android client. Obviously I cannot do this:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
      prefer-token-info: true
    client:
      client-id: xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
      access-token-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo
      client-authentication-scheme: form
      scope: email,profile
    client:
      client-id: xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
      access-token-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo
      client-authentication-scheme: form
      scope: email,profile
```

What is the correct approach and best practice to do this?

Comment: We are on the same both @Heisenbug. I have a feeling that there is a need to manually configure spring security to handle multiple client ids. Maybe this could help guide you on how customizing spring security. https://github.com/techdev-solutions/trackr-backend

Comment: @FrancisZabala thanks for your reply. I tried the following: In .yml I only left server client-id and everything continued to work. Now I'm facing another problem: Android is not receiving accessToken automatically, what is the best practice to get it?

Comment: I really can't help you with android but if you mean how your android client consumes access token, you might want to know how auth0 works. Here's the link to their documentation. https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/android But if you are trying to secure you rest api well, I am still doing some research on it.